# What is the matrix of T in canonical base from $R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We have a linear transformation:

$T: R^3\to R^3$

$T(x)=(mx_1+x_2+x_3, x_1+mx_2+x_3, x_1+x_2+mx_3)$

What is the matrix of T in canonical base from $R^3$? How do I form it ?

Thank you.

Comment: this looks awfully familiar

Comment: @David What is so familiar ?

Comment: This exact linear transformation, along with the matrix written in the canonical basis given in the answer

Comment: If this is an exercise, it is a  bad one, since you cannot tell from the answer whether the matrix came out transposed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Compute $T(1,0,0), T(0,1,0)$ and $T(0,0,1)$. These vectors will be the columns of the matrix.